# Replacing symbols on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have stumbled across on a problem I do not understand why it's even happening (not working).

What I have to do is just to replace 1 's amount value, for some reason I just can't lol.

When user enter amount, in case he enters ",", I have to change it to "." Instantly - live.

Here is the sample..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Uberfix Amount
  $(".form-amount").keyup(function() {
    var amount = $(".form-amount").val();
    $(".form-amount").val().replace(",", ".");
    alert('passed');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-amount" id="textare" value="" placeholder="0.1 BTC - 10 BTC" />
```

Comment: Inside `keyup` use `$(this).val(function(i, value) { return value.replace(',', '.'); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you did not set the value of the textbox after changing its value. See working code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Uberfix Amount
    $(".form-amount").keyup(function() {  
        var $this = $(this), amount = $this.val();
        $this.val(amount.replace(",", "."));
        console.log('passed');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-amount" id="textare" value="" placeholder="0.1 BTC - 10 BTC" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You computed the modified string but do not set it back to the field. If I understand your problem correctly this should work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Uberfix Amount
    $(".form-amount").keyup(function() {
        var amount = $(".form-amount").val();
        $(".form-amount").val(amount.replace(",", "."));
        alert('passed');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-amount" id="textare" value="" placeholder="0.1 BTC - 10 BTC" />
```

Note that `.val()` gets a value while `.val(string)` sets the value of the field to the specified string.